# Inline Array Definition in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Sometimes I wish I could do this in Java:

```
for (int i : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
    System.out.println(i);
```

Unfortunately, I have to do something like this   instead:

```
int [] i = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// ...
```

My recollection is that C++ has this sort of feature. Is there an OOP replacement for inline array definitions (maybe even to the point of instantiating anonymous classes)?

Comment: You could do `for (int i : new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) System.out.println(i);` or `for (int i : Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))`

Comment: @ZouZou which is better?

Comment: In terms of performance? I don't think there is a huge difference between both as `Arrays.asList` just wrap the original array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create the int[] array in the for loop.

```
for (int i : new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) {
   ...
}
```

Here you are making an anonymous int array, which is the closest thing to what you want. You could also loop through a Collection.

Note that this question has nothing to do with OOP. It's merely a matter of syntax. Java supports anonymous arrays/objects just like C++.

Answer (score 7):

I think the closest you are gonna get is:

```
for(int i : new int[] {1,2,3,4})
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to create a separate variable for this.  The syntax `{1, 2, ...}` is valid only for declarations, but you can always say `new int[] {1, 2, ...}`:

```
for (int i : new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
```